# Como enviar varios datos desde android a php

Tags: php, android

Buenos días estoy  haciendo una aplicación en android studio   estoy utilizando php para realizar mi conexión con la base datos **MYSQL**.

Pero cuando hago una consulta con un solo argumento a mi base de datos me funciona pero realice una modificacion para enviar dos argumentos  ya valide en mi php y la consulta me funciona de manera adecuado pero ** Android** me indica un error estoy buscando información pero no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal    anexo mi codigo

**android**

```js
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

  Spinner opciones;
  Button Consultar;
  EditText Cons;
  JSONArray ja;
  Tabla_Consulta tabla;
  LinearLayout linearLayout;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    opciones = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Consultar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_consultar);
    Cons = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Consulta);
    tabla = new Tabla_Consulta(this, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla));





    ArrayAdapter < CharSequence > adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Opc, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.preference_category);
    opciones.setAdapter(adapter);


    Consultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        String selec = opciones.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String selec1 = Cons.getText().toString();

        Consulta("http://10.0.2.2/Libro_Titulo.php?eje=" + opciones.getSelectedItem().toString() + "&" + "Tit=" + Cons.getText().toString());
        //Consulta("http://10.0.2.2/Biblioteca/Libro_Id.php?ide="+Cons.getText().toString());
        //     Log.d("query",   );
        Log.d("query", selec + " " + Cons.getText().toString());
        Log.d("query", selec + " " + selec1);      

      }
    });
  }

  private void Consulta(String URL) {
    Log.i("conexion", URL);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener < String > () { //EL ERROR ESTA EN ESTA LINEA

      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        int j = 1;
        Log.d("reponse", response);
        try {

          ja = new JSONArray(response);
          tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.Opciones);

          for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);


            String id = c.getString("Id");
            String Titulo = c.getString("Titulo");
            String Autor = c.getString("Autor");
            String Editorial = c.getString("Editorial");
            String Facultad = c.getString("Facultad");
            String Reserva = c.getString("Reserva");

            if (Reserva.equals("0")) {
              Reserva = Reserva.replace("0", "Libre");
            } else if (Reserva.equals("1")) {
              Reserva = Reserva.replace("1", "Reserva");
            }

            ArrayList < String > elementos = new ArrayList < String > ();


            elementos.add(Integer.toString(j));
            elementos.add(id);
            elementos.add(Titulo);
            elementos.add(Autor);
            elementos.add(Editorial);
            elementos.add(Facultad);
            elementos.add(Reserva);
            elementos.add("BUTTON");
            tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
            j++;
          }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override

      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> 04-17 15:31:01.276 11093-11238/com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur E/Volley: [429] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://10.0.2.2/Libro_Titulo.php?eje=Id&Tit=1

**php**

```js
< ? php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
include('Conectar.php');
$Tit = $_GET["Tit"];
$eje=$_GET["eje"]; // para solo un archivo
$rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

if ($resultset = getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `tbl_libro` WHERE $eje='$Tit'")) {

  
  $rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

  $i = 0;

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)) {
    
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;

  }

  echo json_encode($rawdata);
}
```

Comment: Ha revisado que los parametros esten correctos?

Comment: @RaulCacacho si revise los parametros y funcione en php como los envias pero si funcionan con un solo parámetro pero lo que necesito es enviar 2

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres es modificar el servicio para que acepte dos parametros y no uno??

Comment: @RaulCacacho si ricardo por eso envió Consolu=Id & Tit=1  pero por algún motivo no me ejecuta cuando llega a la conexion pero no se por que si me funciona con 1 pero al momento de hacerlo con 2  no

Comment: Tienes acceso al codigo del web service para que lo pongas en la pregunta??

Comment: @estebanfabianpatiño el problema en este caso es en el php no puede reconocer un valor que envias al querystring, puedes agregar tu .php?

Comment: @Elenasys ya agregre el php

Comment: @estebanfabianpatiño El query se forma incorrectamente, agrego respuesta! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error indica que estas enviando un parámetro incorrecto o tu php tiene un error:

> com.example.ferney.bibliotecacur E/Volley: [429]
>   BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for
>   http://10.0.2.2/Libro_Titulo.php?eje=Id&Tit=1

aunque recuerda el código de [error 404](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) indica que no encuentra un recurso.

un problema es el query que estas formando es incorrecto:

```
"SELECT * FROM `tbl_libro` WHERE $eje='$Tit'"
```

debe realizarse de esta forma para obtener los valores deseados y concatenarlos al Query:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_libro WHERE ".$eje."='".$Tit."'"
```

Comment: ya realice el cambio pero la falla persiste no se si puede ser el & en la url que mando

Comment: @estebanfabianpatiño lo más rápido para solucionar este tipo de detalles es usar el LogCat o realizar debugging, que te parece si imprimes la url que estas usando, almacena el valor en una variable : String myUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/Libro_Titulo.php?eje=" + opciones.getSelectedItem().toString() + "&" + "Tit=" + Cons.getText().toString()  e imprimelo antes de realizar el llamado Log.i("URL", "Url: " + myUrl); comenta que obtienes?

Comment: ya descubrí el error era sobre la dirección que esta mandan dando era equivocada por que le quite un pedaso sin darme de cuenta

Comment: @estebanfabianpatiño es muy útil hacer debuggin o imprimir los datos para encontrar un posible problema :)

Comment: Las consultas `"SELECT * FROM `tbl_libro` WHERE $eje='$Tit'"` y `"SELECT * FROM tbl_libro WHERE ".$eje."='".$Tit."'"` son equivalentes y ambas sufren problemas de seguridad (inyección SQL). Además, la afirmación de que el error indica que un parámetro enviado es incorrecto es falsa. Tú mismo indicas que es por un recurso inexistente en el servidor, probablemente por haber puesto un nombre de archivo PHP incorrecto, no por sus parámetros. Por lo que @estebanfabianpatiño , me gustaría saber por qué has marcado esta respuesta como correcta (y por qué tres personas la han votado positivamente).

Comment: Todo lo anterior lo digo sin menospreciar el tiempo y trabajo realizado por @Elenasys , lo hago con visión de futura utilidad a otras personas que sufran un mensaje de error similar y vengan a esta pregunta buscando una solución útil. Deberías editar la respuesta y agregar (enfatizar) que el problema principal es el error en la URL. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

**Error era el direccionamiento de la url**

```js
 Consulta("http://10.0.2.2/Biblioteca/Libro_Titulo.php?eje="+ opciones.getSelectedItem().toString() +"&Tit=" + Cons.getText().toString());
```

El error era que la dirección url esta mal por que no se le esta indicando por donde esta el proyecto (Biblioteca)  por ese motivo no encontraba donde el archivo php